# Undefined Reference Using Static Library

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I have an extremely simple program using functions provided in Portals Network Programming Interface version 4.0 (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/portals4/source/checkout) for source code).  Below is my code

**main.cxx:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <portals4.h>

int main() {
  if (PtlInit() == PTL_OK) {
    printf("Successfully initialized...\n");
    PtlFini();
  }
  else {
    printf("Failed to initialize...\n");
    abort();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Makefile:**

```
.SUFFIXES: .cxx .o .h

CXX = g++

TARGET = test
SRCS   = main.cxx
OBJS   = $(SRCS:.cxx=.o)

PORTALS_ROOT = /home/brooks8/portals4
PORTALS_INCS = -I$(PORTALS_ROOT)/include
PORTALS_LIBS = -L$(PORTALS_ROOT)/lib -lportals -lportals_runtime

CXXFLAGS = -std=c++0x $(PORTALS_INCS)
LDFLAGS  = $(PORTALS_LIBS)

%.o: %.cxx
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<

$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(SRCS) : $(HEADERS)

clean :
    rm -rf *.o $(TARGET)
```

When I run `make`:

```
g++ -c -std=c++0x -I/home/brooks8/portals4/include main.cxx
g++ -o test main.o -L/home/brooks8/portals4/lib -lportals -lportals_runtime
main.o: In function `main':
main.cxx:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `PtlInit()'
main.cxx:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `PtlFini()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

I have Portals 4.0 installed in my home directory (`/home/brooks8/portals4`) with the `portals4.h` header file located at `/home/brooks8/portals4/include/portals4.h`.  Within the header file, both functions are clearly defined, as well as being defined in the Portals 4.0 Specification (see [here](http://www.cs.sandia.gov/Portals/portals40.pdf)) on pages 38 (`Section 3.5.1`) and 39 (`Secion 3.5.2`) respectively.

I am unsure as to why I am receiving the undefined references and would appreciate any input toward my situation.  If I can provide any more information to assist with my issue, please let me know.

Thank you.

Edit:

Results from `nm /home/brooks8/portals4/lib/libportals.a`:

```
...
libportals_ib_la-ptl_fat_lib.o:
0000000000000000 r .LC0
0000000000000000 r .LC1
000000000000000e r .LC2
0000000000000011 r .LC3
0000000000000070 T PtlFini
0000000000000080 T PtlInit
...
```

Results from `file main.o`:

```
main.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Results from `file ~/portals4/lib/libportals.a`:

```
~/portals4/lib/libportals.a: current ar archive
```

Object files in `~/portals/lib/libportals.a`:

```
libportals_ib_la-ptl_atomic.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_buf.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_conn.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_ct.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_ct_common.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_data.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_eq.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_eq_common.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_evloop.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_fat_lib.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_id.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_iface.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_init.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_iov.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_le.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_md.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_me.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_misc.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_move.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_mr.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_ni.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_obj.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_param.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_pt.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_recv.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_tgt.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_rdma.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_iface_ib.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_mem.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_queue.o
libportals_ib_la-ptl_shmem.o
```

Results from `file XXXX.o`:

```
XXXX.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Comment: And the output from `$ nm /home/brooks8/portals4/lib/libportals.a` and `$ nm /home/brooks8/portals4/lib/libportals_runtime.a` is what?

Comment: @trojanfoe edited my post to include useful parts the results from your requests.  I am unable to paste the entire results for just the first command, due to the length.  The second one does not include either function

Comment: OK can you now tell us what `$ file main.o` and `$ file ~/.../libportals.a` etc show?  I'd like to see the architectures being used.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping that `$ file X.a` would show the CPU architecture being used (it does under OSX).  Can you unpack the archive to a temp directory and see what arch the `.o` are files are please?

Comment: @trojanfoe Added. I'm assuming you wanted the results from `ar -t XXX.a`

Comment: No, I wanted to check the architecture (using `file X.o`) of the objects within the static library, so you need to extract the objects and run the command on them.  However I now suspect that @crowder's answer might be correct, so I would try that first.

Comment: @trojanfoe Okay I extracted the object files and ran `file XXX.o` and I received the same result for all of them: `ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`

Comment: Well then I'm at a loss to explain what is going on.  I would try to use `extern "C"` (as suggested by @crowder) and to use `#include "portals4.h"` to ensure you aren't picking-up a system-version of the library (a slim possibility).  If that doesn't work then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Nothing successful :( I will contact the developers to inquire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building your app as a C++ app, it's possible you need to wrap your #include  with extern "C", like so:

```
extern "C" {
    #include <portal4.h>
    // other c-style headers here
}
```

Usually library authors manage this for themselves, but it's possible portal doesn't in this case?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: If it works, it's an answer, is it not? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the difference....

Comment: It just seems like a stab in the dark.  Looking at the linker error message it doesn't seem like it's looking for name-mangled symbols, so it looks like `extern "C"` is already in operation.

Comment: Usually linkers demangle for error messages, these days.

In any case, I wouldn't have been able to include formatted code for a "comment".

Comment: I think you are better approaching this with comments first; for example are `main.o` and the `.a` files the same architecture? (the next question I was going to ask), once the OP had confirmed the output of the `nm` command I asked above.  There are several possible reasons for this failure and adding a speculative answer for each won't help future visitors.

Comment: ... having said that, and then following the link to the source (as posted by the OP), there is no `extern "C"` in the header file, so I think you are right!

Comment: Turns out I managed to delete the `-lportals -lportals_runtime` when I previously added the extern, causing the undefined references... Replacing the options and including the extern does in fact work.

Comment: It might be reasonable to file a bug against portals to fix this:

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

.... header stuff ....

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

is the common pattern